# How to retrieve specific value from Collection Initializer Syntax

Tags: c#, collections, initializer

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
                new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "John"},
                new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "Steve"},
                new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "Bill"},
                new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "Bill"},
                new Student() { Id = 4, Name = "Ram" },
                new Student() { Id = 5, Name = "Ron" }
            };
```

I'm using Collection Initializer syntax. I know the way to print all the Name's value by using foreach.
But, how to retrieve a specific value (e.g retrieve "Steve") ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indexer to access an item in the list by its index, e.g.:

```
string nameOfTheSecondItem = studentList[1].Name;
```

`studentList[1]` returns the second item in `studentList` since the indexes are zero-based.

Also note that trying to access an item on an index that doesn't exist will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, so you should check whether `studentList.Count > 1` before using the above code unless you know for sure that the list always contains at least two items.

Comment: If the "Steve" is not at index 1. It will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to find an element in a `List`. A common way is to use `LINQ` like below

Find all Students whose name are `Steve`. This returns an `IEnumerable<Student>`, which can be used for further processing or printed out by looping over it, or can be converted to an array or List using `ToArray()` or `ToList()` extensions of `IEnumerable`

```
var allSteves = studentList.Where(s => s.Name == "Steve");
```

If you are sure there is only one `Steve`, then you can use the `FirstOrDefault()` extension method

```
var steve = studentList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Steve");
```

This will either return a null record (assuming `Student` is a class) or a `Student` record with `Steve` as name. You can use the `First()` method, if you want LINQ to throw an exception when a Student record with Name = Steve is not found.

There is also a `List.Find` which can help, but the LINQ methods apply to all `IEnuerable`, including arrays and lists

Needless to say, you can implement more complex logic for your match criteria inside the `Where`, `First`, `Find` etc methods.